# What was Swami Vivekananda's opinion on Nagajurna and Abhinavagupta?

Tags: tantra, vivekananda, buddhism, kashmiri-shaivism

What was Swami Vivekananda's opinion on Nagajurna? Did he ever talk about Abhinavgupta or Nagajurna at any one of his talks?

I know he has talked about Buddha, Jainas and others but never saw him talking about more modern forms of Buddhism and Tantras.

Edit: He did talked about Tantric karma kandas - https://vivekavani.com/swami-vivekananda-quotes-tantra/